# Private Encrypted Key Workaround with Requests - CA Certificate

Tags: python, python-requests

I’m still a novice but my Googleing has led me to not find any answers. I know that the Requests library does not allow for encrypted private keys.

Does anyone have a workaround, either using Requests or something similar?

Comment: Requests is an HTTP client library. Can you explain where "encrypted private keys" fit in? What are these keys and how are they used? Your title mentions CA certificate, but why would the CA private key be used in an HTTP request? Perhaps you're referring to a *client certificate*?

Comment: @JonathonReinhart I guess http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#client-side-certificates is meant

Comment: Sorry, specifically referring to here: https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#ca-certificates

Comment: The CA certificate bundle is the set of CA certificates that you want to trust to sign certs for sites to which you make requests. There are no private keys involved with CA certificates (from a client's perspective).

Comment: @AlexBall Why do you need private key for CAs? You only need public certs there.  Maybe you mean client-side certificates?

Comment: Right above that section in the docs, it says  *"The private key to your local certificate must be unencrypted. Currently, Requests does not support using encrypted keys."* As I mentioned, that applies to a **client certificate** which is an entirely different, rarely used mechanism for clients to authenticate with the server.

Answer (score 1):

If CAs are implied,  no private keys are required.

If client certificates are implied, you could implement custom HttpAdapter like this: https://github.com/requests/requests/issues/1573#issuecomment-336146209. Then you can use it like this:

```
session = requests.Session()
session.mount('https://', SSLAdapter(certfile, keyfile, password))
session.get(url)
```